# How do I replace the commas in my string without affecting the commas in my CSV file?

Tags: java, string, csv, parsing

I have a data set which I'm loading with strings and it contains something like this:

"10, 14, 15, "20,152", 37, "42,167", 22"

How can I use Java to parse the data so that the commas inside the quotation marks are safely removed and the other commas are not affected?

Comment: You need to treat the quotation marks correctly, as enclosing a column value. This is fairly trivial.

Comment: What do you mean by treating the quotation marks correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to keep the quotation marks something like this would work. If not then you can edit it a little to also remove the quotation marks.

```
public String process(String input) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    boolean insideDoubleQuotes = false;
    for (char currentCharacter : input.toCharArray()) {

      if (currentCharacter == '"') {
        insideDoubleQuotes = !insideDoubleQuotes;
      } else if (currentCharacter == ',' && insideDoubleQuotes) {
        continue;
      }

      result.append(currentCharacter);
    }

    return result.toString();
  }
```

Comment: `if (currentCharacter == '"') {
        comma = !comma;` -- that doesn't seem to make sense. please name your variables appropriately to their function. `comma` should instead be something like `insideDoubleQuotes`.

Comment: Good comment, lessons not to rush an answer.

Comment: Perhaps the second condition should be: `currentCharacter == ',' && insideDoubleQuotes`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String input = "'10,11', '12,14', 15, '20,152', 37, '42,167', 22"; //
        String[] list = input.split("'"); // Split the string using "'" as delimeter(change it to quotation mark)
        ArrayList<String> elements = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                        // condition to check if it is outside/outside the quotation mark
            if (i % 2 != 0) {  // if inside a quotation mark
                if (!list[i].trim().isEmpty()) { // so that spaces will not be included
                    elements.add(list[i].trim()); // add the element to the list
                }
            } else { //if outside the quotation marks
                String[] tmp = list[i].split(","); // split the regular comma separated values
                for (String s : tmp) { // iterate each splits
                    if (!s.trim().isEmpty()) { // check for spaces
                        elements.add(s.trim()); // add element to the list
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        for (String s : elements) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }

}
```